# Google Map won't display when page accessed through Rails urlhelper generated link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am new to Rails and having trouble understanding why my map won't display.  My source is [here](https://github.com/SplendidStrontium/bjl-desco) and currently hosted [here](https://hidden-shelf-8291.herokuapp.com/) for testing purposes.

When I load the [home page](https://hidden-shelf-8291.herokuapp.com), and click on the button for the contact page, the google map will not show.  However, if I access the contact page [directly](https://hidden-shelf-8291.herokuapp.com/contact), the map will load just fine.  After I've loaded the map correctly once, I can click around the site and keep the map (cached?).

I've located a lot of users having similar issues, some of which were fixed with a $(document).on('pageinit', function() .... style declaration, but this and other variants seem to be [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/) as of jquery 1.9.

Other users said they were able to fix the problem by attaching "rel='external'" to their nav bar links, but since I have generated the nav bar with urlhelper, this doesn't seem to be an option for me.

In lieu of an 'easy' fix, am I able to simply force a page refresh using my pages controller?

**app/assets/javascripts/contact_map.js**

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function initialize() {
  var bjlLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7547655,-73.8048775);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: bjlLoc,
    zoom: 13
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: bjlLoc,
    title: 'B.J. Laura & Son',
    map: map
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/pages.scss**

```
#contact-info{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

#map-container{
  border: none;
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 325px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

#mapcanvas{
  border: none;
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= yield :head %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body id="bdycontainer">
  <canvas id="blogo" width="1000" height="120">...</canvas>
  <nav>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <% [["Home", :root], ["About", :about], ["Contact", :contact]].each do |name,url| %>
      <li><%= link_to_unless_current(name, url) %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app/views/pages/contact.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <title>Contact B.J. Laura</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<% end %>

<br/>
<div id="contact-info">...</div>

<div id="map-container">
  <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
</div>

<br/>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'data-turbolinks-track' => true` is actually causing this problem. Turn off the `data-trubolinks-track` to use the Google maps API without having to refresh the page.

Comment: I went ahead and completely removed turbolinks from my project.  It's working!  Thank you!

Comment: You could also listen to the 'page:load' event (in addition to using `$(document).ready()`). [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: @Paige do have a look at the question mentioned by Stephen. That's how you can use Turbo-links with Google maps api.